# Is there any way for object-level expiration in aws s3 buckets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

For example : One object tends to expire after 10 days , other one after 30 days of creation date. How can i ensure this object level expiration ?

I went through some guides that mentions rule for whole bucket but not for object specific expiration.

Comment: By expiration, I presume you mean "delete this object after _x_ days"? Does every object have its own expiration duration, or are they grouped in some way (eg all objects in a particular path have the same expiration duration)? Is there any problem with standardizing on 30 days (aside from the extra storage cost)? Is the expiration duration known at the time of object creation, or is it determined externally later? Feel free to edit your question to add more details.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes i mean every object has a expiration days param x that tells 'delete this object after x days' . And this x param will be known at the time of object creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no in-built capability to perform daily deletions on a per-object basis, but one way to achieve it would be:

- When the objects are created, add a **metadata tag** with the desired deletion date
- Configure **Amazon CloudWatch Events** to trigger an AWS Lambda function once per day
- The **AWS Lambda function** can look for objects in the bucket that have reached/passed the deletion date stored in metadata
- The function can then **delete the objects**

This would give you the ability to specify daily expirations.

Comment: John, don't you think that controlling this in DynamoDB would better suit this specific problem? i.e add the object's metadata in DynamoDB (key and expirationDate) and have a CloudWatch Event fire a lambda to poll the DynamoDB table instead? One reason is that maybe not all objects will ever expire, reducing the amount of items that would potentially be inserted in the table. And it just doesn't sound right to me to scan s3 buckets, but I may be in the wrong direction here.

Comment: Yes, perhaps. I was assuming that every object would be eventually deleted. If some objects are not deleted, then the number of S3 objects could grow quite large and it would be inefficient to scan them all each day. That's why I was hoping that the objects could be put into specific directories (prefixes) based on their desired duration and then the normal Object Expiration function could delete them without having to write any code. If there's going to be a large number of objects hanging around, then using a datastore would be better than scanning all object metadata.

Comment: Another option if there are lots of objects... They could activate [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily listing of objects in the bucket _including metadata_. This could activate a Lambda function that would simply parse the file, look at the metadata and then delete the objects. No database or bucket scanning required!

Comment: Indeed much cleaner options. Thanks for sharing that!

Comment: S3 Inventory option looks a big relief. Thanks @JohnRotenstein